# How does Java allocate memory for objects?

Tags: java, object, memory

I've been reading through some android tutorials and I saw this:

```
public class HelloService extends Service {
  private Looper mServiceLooper;
  private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;
  ...
```

I assume when you declare an integer like `public int num1;` the compiler allocates integer-size memory for it right when it sees it.  But how could it do something like this for all objects?  Are all objects allocated the same memory and being more specific is just for type-safety/readability purposes?

Comment: These are just pointers to `null` declaring them like this - all pointers are the same "size" in memory.  You don't actually end up allocating different sizes of memory until you do `new Looper()` and `new ServiceHandler()`. These are a bit different from `public int num1`, which aren't Objects.  Can you narrow down your question a bit? I'm sure a proper answer to something like this could end up being an entire book.

Comment: Google `java memory stack heap`.

Comment: I agree with @Chris. The idea is that the java compiler (`javac`) generates the bytecode (.class) for your Java source (.java). The .class file can then be (potentially) 'run' by the Java virtual machine (JVM). The class file is then initially 'interpreted' by the JVM and the bytecode instructions executed. The rules of this interpretation are described in the Java Virtual Machine Specification. The instruction `new`, when executed, ends up allocating space for the object.

Answer (score 1):

mServiceLooper and mServiceHandler fields are simply pointers to instances of their corresponding classes. All pointers occupy the same space, e.g. 4 bytes, it depends on JVM.